# Make UIAlertView trigger by variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Some QR code scanner apps will show the result (URL or something) by a alert once they finish scanning, so I want to do the same thing and display the result (integer number) of my video processing by alert. My video processing function is a delegate method. I read a few examples of `UIAlertView`, but buttons are needed to trigger the alert. In my case, the alert need to be shown after calculating the variable `result`. But if I add the alert in my `processImage` function:

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {
    int result;
    videoProcessing() {
    ...      
    result = 10
    }

    if (result == 10) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The code is" message:@"10" 
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

My app will be terminated because of error:

```
2014-04-17 11:11:02.189 DotReader[3813:1803] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:388
2014-04-17 11:11:02.190 DotReader[3813:1803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:] may only be called from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183ab6950 0x18ffbc1fc 0x183ab6810 0x1845eedb4 0x186aa8fc0 0x186aa8eec 0x186aa8b50 0x186aa6588 0x186aa565c 0x186f811d0 0x186f81698 0x186b00c7c 0x186affa04 0x186f83010 0x10007ad0c 0x10013c374 0x1827b8434 0x190594014 0x190593fd4 0x19059a4a8 0x1905964c0 0x19059b0f4 0x19059b4fc 0x1907296bc 0x19072954c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Can anyone tell me how to add `UIAlertView` correctly?

Comment: You are adding/displaying the alert correctly. The only thing you are doing wrong is that you seem to be displaying it from a background thread, not the main thread.

Comment: Displaying it from a background thread is incorrect, as mentioned, but it shouldn't make it crash in my experience. However what might is if you are displaying it twice in very rapid succession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are calling the alert in the thread operation. Try the code below:

```
-(void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {
    int result;
    videoProcessing(){
    ...      
    result = 10
    }

    if(result == 10){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertMessage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}   

-(void)showAlertMessage{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The code is" message:@"10" 
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

Comment: a typo, should be `waitUntilDone:YES`. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

All UI events should be called from the main thread

```
if (result == 10) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The code is" message:@"10"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {
    int result;
    videoProcessing() {
        ...      
        result = 10
    }

    if (result == 10) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The code is" message:@"10" 
            delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps... :)